# Run Vue application from AWS Lambda http link

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-lambda

I want to build web application which takes last part of link as argument:

```
https://aws-lambda/index/water
```

here the water is an argument. Then server will take this argument and call the database to get some data.

The server response will be a SPA Vue JS application which contain (or have access) to data associated with argument from previous step. The arguments set could be large, but follow pattern:

```
https://aws-lambda/index/water
https://aws-lambda/index/water/intro
https://aws-lambda/index/water/description
https://aws-lambda/index/snow
https://aws-lambda/index/snow/intro
https://aws-lambda/index/snow/description
...
```

To do this I did:

- AWS lambda function which takes user http call. Then it takes last part of link and loads data.
- Simple vue application and build with

  npm run build

I deployed it to AWS S3 and I see it works there (I have opened http access to bucket with application)

Then I thought to run Vue application as result of lambda function http call. To do this I took same index.html as I have at deployed on S3 Vue application and used as response of my lambda function. This gives me error about files called from index.html not found but I fixed links and all files loaded without errors, but Vue application page is empty. Here the html response I got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>front</title>
    <base href="http://ghr-showroom.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com">
    <link href=/static/css/app.0b9ee66846b76d347f3d7105394fbb09.css
        rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
    <div id=app></div>
    <script type=text/javascript
        src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script>
    <script type=text/javascript
        src=/static/js/vendor.572ec9cc135a64e9c562.js></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.d75fc84987a696677f3c.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to run Vue application from AWS Lambda http link?